# weka apply 2 or more algorithms som,j48, naive bayes

Tags: java, python, data-mining, weka, som

I'm using weka and I have been trying apply j48 on SOM (self organizing map), I get the cluster/instance of SOM and it puts in j48 but this is not working so, I search online and no examples of combine 2 algorithms appears
I need to apply SOM then j48 and least naive bayes

```
 def aplicarArbol(self):
        instace = self.som.getClusters()
        instace.setClassIndex(self.data.numAttributes() - 1)
        j48 = J48arbol()
        j48.buildClassifier(instace)
        print(instace)
        return j48
```

Comment: You need to add more context to this so people can better help you.

Comment: i need to train a dataset first with som then with j48 and final with bayes. if you have an example of training a single data set with multiple algorithms i will be very gracefull